# Does SSL pinning in android app affect working of iOS app using same server?

Tags: android, ios, public-key-pinning

I am implementing SSL public key pinning on my android app. After implementation on the android app and adding Expect-CT header at the server will it affect my iOS app on which SSL pinning is not implemented?

Answer (score 1):

SSL pinning is an implementation detail of the app, so implementing on Android won't impact iOS.

The Expect-CT header, however, is actually for Certificate Transparency, and so un-related to SSL pinning. It will have no impact on either Android or iOS apps currently although could potentially in webviews where the browsers are starting to add in support.

To support CT on Android, look at [certificate-transparency-android](https://github.com/babylonhealth/certificate-transparency-android). For iOS, [AppTransportSecurity](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW33) has a `NSRequiresCertificateTransparency` that needs to be set to `YES`, the default is `NO`, i.e. by default CT is not enabled within iOS apps.